# Inverse cubic centimeter to inverse cubic meter

Tags: inverse

If I have $x$  $ cm^{-3}$, how can I convert it to $y$  $ m^{-3}$?

What is $y$ in terms of $x$?

Comment: Obviously $y=10^{6}x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x\cm^{-3} = x\cdot(10^{-2}\m)^{-3} = x\cdot 10^{6}\m^{-3}$$